# Diffraction pattern of SLM and polarization

Tags: visible-light, polarization, diffraction

I am trying to analyze the effect of the polarization on a diffraction pattern generated by phase only modulation in SLM (Spatial Light modulator).

and I want to know why changing the polarization from P to S will change the intensity of the Zero and first diffraction order. Like in one Polarization the Zero diffraction order have a high light intensity them changing the polarization will lead to move all the intensity to the first diffraction order so the zero order vanish.

thanks.